# How to convert complex query to Model in a LINQ to Entities query

Tags: entity-framework, linq

```
public class Gateway : ModelBase
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int SystemGroupId { get; set; }
        public string DeviceName { get; set; }
        public string MacAddress { get; set; }
        public bool Enabled { get; set; } 
    }

public class SystemGroup : ModelBase
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I am joining these two tables.

```
var Query = (from g in dbContext.Gateways 
join s in dbContext.SystemGroups on g.SystemGroupId equals s.Id
select new {
Id = g.Id,
SystemGroupId = g.SystemGroupId,
SystemGroupName = s.Name,
DeviceName = g.DeviceName,
MacAddress = g.MacAddress,
DeviceType = g.DeviceType,
Enabled = g.Enabled });
```

and I am sorting these result set using the below code.

```
if (sortParameter == Resources.ViewResources.Views.SystemGroup)
   Query = Query.OrderBy(x => x.SystemGroupName);
else if (sortParameter == Resources.ViewResources.Views.DeviceName)
   Query = Query.OrderBy(x => x.DeviceName);
else
   Query = Query.OrderBy(x => x.Id);
```

Till now it is working as expected. Finally, I want to convert it to `Gateway`.

```
return Query.Select(x => new Gateway {
 Id= x.Id, 
 SystemGroupId = x.SystemGroupId, 
 DeviceName = x.DeviceName, 
 MacAddress=x.MacAddress, 
 DeviceType= x.DeviceType, 
 Enabled= x.Enabled}).ToList();
```

While converting to `Gateway`, it is throwing the error:

> The entity or complex type 'Models.Context.Gateway' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Answer (score 3):

In Linq-to-Entities you can only project to an anonymous type or a regular class. You can't project to an existing entity type. You can with linq-to-objects like so

```
return Query.Select new {
Id= x.Id, 
SystemGroupId = x.SystemGroupId, 
DeviceName = x.DeviceName, 
MacAddress=x.MacAddress, 
DeviceType= x.DeviceType, 
Enabled= x.Enabled}).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new Gateway {
        Id= x.Id, 
SystemGroupId = x.SystemGroupId, 
DeviceName = x.DeviceName, 
MacAddress=x.MacAddress, 
DeviceType= x.DeviceType, 
Enabled= x.Enabled}).ToList();
```

I didnt test this one,Please do comment after try this one.then i can help you to get your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If i convert into "Enumerable" it will work. But it will hit the performance. I want to convert it as a IQueryable only.

Comment: Then you can use AsQueryable instead of AsEnumerable.

Comment: Or u can use ToList() instead of AsEnumerable().The advantage of using AsEnumerable vs. ToList is that AsEnumerable does not execute the query. AsEnumerable preserves deferred execution and does not build an often useless intermediate list.

On the other hand, when forced execution of a LINQ query is desired, ToList can be a way to do that.

AsQueryable can be used to make an enumerable collection accept expressions in LINQ statements.